# What factors affect sleep propensity?

Tags: sleep, sleep-cycles

What environmental and personal factors affect the amount of time it takes to fall to sleep? How can some people go to bed in 5 min where others take an hour?

Some factors I’ve thought about include:

- Temperature
- Habits/upbringing
- Screen time
- Sun
- Appetite

To what extent to these play a role in the time it takes to fall to sleep? Are there other more important factors?

Comment: Hi, I did a bit of editing to try to make it seem like something people would approve of. (Personally I think there’s a good and answerable question there.) Hopefully it’s helpful, but feel free to roll back anything that you don’t like.